# How to trigger an event when the mouse hits the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a menu bar that works similarly to the windows task bar. One of property that I want to emulate is hide/show when the mouse goes in the bottom of the page. 
How can I detect when the mouse is in the bottom of the page?

First of all, is there a plugin for JQuery or similar libraries which already implement this action?

A possible solution is to use a invisible div in the bottom which triggers the event when the mouse gets in. I was wondering if there is a better solution than this.

Comment: Have you looked into the `mousemove` event?

Comment: yes but it will trigger an event for each movement into the "triggering" area. I need that the event is trigger just once

Comment: Either add an invisible area at the bottom or use the mouse move event and test for the mouse position which you'll find in the event object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using jQuery is not a problem

```
window.onmousemove= function(e){
 if(e.y>= $(document).height()-10)
    alert('you did hit the bottom!');
}
```

Will do. check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/fkes4/)

*note: i've given a 10px breathing space*

**Update:** Fiddle with a taskbar like div - [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/fkes4/2/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this -- >

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(event){
    var docheight = $( document ).height() - 10; //subtracted with 10 just to be safe with checking the condition below

    if(event.pageY > docheight){
        alert("you have reached socument bottom");
         //write your code here
    }

  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d22br/2/)

Comment: Well, how is this different from my solution?

Comment: technically there is nothing different .mine is just a lil easy to understand and has more explanation in the fiddle .But your first fiddle was not working properly and i already posted the answer so decided to keep it as it is .